# Why can't I assign (1<<31) to an ulong var? (Error 25 Constant value ... cannot be converted ...)

Tags: c#, ulong

Why does this assigning produce a comile error: `Constant value '-2147483648' cannot be converted to a 'ulong'` and I have to use `unchecked (...)` for this case?

```
ulong xDummy30 = (1 << 30); // works
ulong xDummy31 = (1 << 31); // ERROR 25 Constant value '-2147483648' cannot be converted to a 'ulong'
ulong xDummy32 = (1 << 32); // works
```

Using this instead works:

```
ulong xDummy31a = unchecked((ulong)(1 << 31));
// or
ulong xDummy31b = (1ul << 31); //  comment from Regis Portalez
```

**Edit**
The Question [Why do I have to cast 0 (zero) when doing bitwise operations in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056327/why-do-i-have-to-cast-0-zero-when-doing-bitwise-operations-in-c) has a similar answer and the reason for the observed behaviour is the same. But they are different questions.

Comment: 1<<31 might be evaluated with int32 operands. Can you evaluate 1ul<<31?

Comment: @RegisPortalez works (like the unchecked(...) version). Is there any reason for that?

Comment: @boboes this is just the default way C# treats simple numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have to cast 0 (zero) when doing bitwise operations in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056327/why-do-i-have-to-cast-0-zero-when-doing-bitwise-operations-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [MSDN ulong reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx) all your integer literals 1, 30, 31 are regarded as int:

> When an integer literal has no suffix, its type is the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long,

According to [MSDN << operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/a1sway8w.aspx) the result of the  << operation is also an int. When yo shift by 30 the result is positive, when shifting by 31 the result is a negative int which can't be assigned to an ulong.

**Edit: HVD pointed me an error in the following. Thanks HVD!**

*Start Error - When shifting 32 bits, the compiler knows you want an ulong, and thus the result of the shift operation is a positive long, which can be converted to an unlong - end error*

The correct reason why 1<<32 does not lead to compiler error is in the provided link to operator <<:

> If the first operand is an int, the shift count is given by the
>   low-order five bits of the second operand. That is, the actual shift
>   count is 0 to 31 bits.

32 to binary: 0010 0000; low order five bits: 0 0000, So the actual performed shift is 1 << 0, which results to the int with the value 1, which of course can be assigned to an ulong.

To solve this, make sure that your number 1 is a long. In that case 1<<31 is still a positive long.

> You can also use suffixes to specify the type of the literal according to the following rules:
>   If you use L, the type of the literal integer will be either long or ulong according to its size.

So 1L is a long; 1L <<31 is a positive long, and thus can be assigned to an ulong

Comment: "When shifting 32 bits, the compiler knows you want an ulong" -- Eh? That's not how it works. `1 << 32` has type `int`, and a value of `1`, as required by the C# language specification which dictates that only the bottom 5 bits of the count are used if the LHS has type `int` or `uint`. This is also mentioned in the documentation you link to.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to my question and the accepted answer here is a note:

Quoting first the example of my question:

```
ulong xDummy30 = (1 << 30); // works
ulong xDummy31 = (1 << 31); // ERROR 25 Constant value '-2147483648' cannot be converted to a 'ulong'
ulong xDummy32 = (1 << 32); // works
```

It is correct that this assignement brings **no compile error:**

```
ulong xDummy32 = (1 << 32);
```

but it **does not "work"**, contrary to what I wrote in my question. After this the result of `xDummy32` **is not** `4294967296` but it is `1`. Therefore bit shifts `> 30` must be written this way:

```
ulong xDummy32 = (1UL << 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var a = (1<<31);
    Console.WriteLine(a);

    ulong num = unchecked((ulong)(1<<31));
    Console.WriteLine(num);

Output:
-2147483648
18446744071562067968
```

1<<31 value is unable to fit into uInt64

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/TfjnSZ

Comment: Range of  ulong is 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Comment: Why should 2^31 be unable to fit into an `UInt64`? The range of `UInt64` is `[0, 2^64-1]`. You just have to use correct datatypes. `var e = 1L << 62;` works perfectly.

Comment: "fit" is the wrong word. I believe you are looking for "convert".